# open cv xcode c++ variable has incomplete type cv::Mat

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

There seems to be little help with opencv out in world hence my asking
so I have been getting an error saying " variable has incomplete type 'cv::Mat' " at the first line of code in my loop i also have an error in the second line of code in my loop saying " use of undeclared identifier 'pic ". also if anyone has any basic opencv code that simply displays an image and would like to share it for educational purposes as I am trying to lear basics for a larger that would be greatly appreciated
below is my code :

```
#include <iostream>

#include "/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "/usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "/usr/local/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    VideoCapture pic(0,0);
    while (true)
   {
        Mat Webcam;
        pic.read(Webcam);
        imshow("Webcam",Webcam);
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `VideoCapture pic(0);`, and include only `opencv2/opencv.hpp`